# JNI - java ArrayList conversion to c++ std::string*

Tags: java, c++, string, arraylist, java-native-interface

I am trying to make a data conversion with JNI in c++. I have come into trouble working with *java*'s *ArrayList* of *strings*, since I have not been able to convert such a data into a *c++* *vector* or *std::string**.

I would like to know how this conversion can be made without sacrificing too much performance, if possible. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Performance is critical for my project, so I would like to stick to JNI if possible.

Comment: A Java string is a counted sequence of Unicode/UTF-16 code-units, representing an uncounted sequence of Unicode characters. std::string is a counted sequence of 8-bit code-units, with the character set and encoding typically Unicode/UTF-8 or something similar to Windows-1252. GetStringUTFChars gets the _modified_ UTF-8 encoding of a Java string and adds a 0x00 terminator. Depending on the characters in the string, it can differ significantly from the UTF-8 encoding. You might consider `String.getBytes(String charsetName)` or `String.getBytes()`. What do consumers of the std::string expect?

Comment: @TomBlodget That doesn't explain how to represent ArrayList in JNI.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I wrote a comment asking for refinement of the requirements for the `std::string`. The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24405079/2226988) covers the `ArrayList` to `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::string[]`. Perhaps, you have a question about the answer or an entirely new question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know if this fits your performance requirements, but it may be a good start.

For both options assume that `jobject jList;` is your ArrayList.

### **Option 1**

Convert the List into an array and iterate on the array (maybe more applicable if you have a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList)

```cpp
// retrieve the java.util.List interface class
jclass cList = env->FindClass("java/util/List");

// retrieve the toArray method and invoke it
jmethodID mToArray = env->GetMethodID(cList, "toArray", "()[Ljava/lang/Object;");
if(mToArray == NULL)
    return -1;
jobjectArray array = (jobjectArray)env->CallObjectMethod(jList, mToArray);

// now create the string array
std::string* sArray = new std::string[env->GetArrayLength(array)];
for(int i=0;i<env->GetArrayLength(array);i++) {
    // retrieve the chars of the entry strings and assign them to the array!
    jstring strObj = (jstring)env->GetObjectArrayElement(array, i);
    const char * chr = env->GetStringUTFChars(strObj, NULL);
    sArray[i].append(chr);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(strObj, chr);
}

// just print the array to std::cout
for(int i=0;i<env->GetArrayLength(array);i++) {
    std::cout << sArray[i] << std::endl;
}
```

### **Option 2**

An alternative would be to use the `List.size()` and `List.get(int)` methods to retrieve the data from the list. As you use an ArrayList this solution would also be okay as the ArrayList is an RandomAccessList.

```cpp
// retrieve the java.util.List interface class
jclass cList = env->FindClass("java/util/List");

// retrieve the size and the get method
jmethodID mSize = env->GetMethodID(cList, "size", "()I");
jmethodID mGet = env->GetMethodID(cList, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;");

if(mSize == NULL || mGet == NULL)
    return -1;

// get the size of the list
jint size = env->CallIntMethod(jList, mSize);
std::vector<std::string> sVector;

// walk through and fill the vector
for(jint i=0;i<size;i++) {
    jstring strObj = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(jList, mGet, i);
    const char * chr = env->GetStringUTFChars(strObj, NULL);
    sVector.push_back(chr);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(strObj, chr);
}

// print the vector
for(int i=0;i<sVector.size();i++) {
    std::cout << sVector[i] << std::endl;
}
```

_edited: replaced JNI_FALSE with NULL_
_edited: replaced insert with push_back_

Comment: I am not sure if it fits the performance requisites but, as you already indicated, it's a good start. It works perfectly. I will now try to reduce the work needed to make the conversion. Thanks!

Comment: You should pass NULL instead of JNI_FALSE to GetStringUTFChars. In JNI, `jboolean *isCopy` parameters are optional output parameters and are for informational purposes only, meaning it has no bearing on whether to call the release function.

Comment: In **Option 2**, why are you using `vector.insert` instead of `vector.push_back`?

Comment: Good point, I really don't know why I haven't used push_back back then. Immediately, adjusted the example (also for toms comment, I should have done this earlier).

Answer (score 4):

You could also use classic java iterators from within JNI, having the loop equally optimized both for `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

```
jobject jIterator = env->CallObjectMethod(jList, env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(jList), "iterator", "()Ljava/util/Iterator;"));
jmethodID nextMid = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(jIterator), "next", "()Ljava/lang/Object;");
jmethodID hasNextMid = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(jIterator), "hasNext", "()Z");

while (env->CallBooleanMethod(jIterator, hasNextMid)) {
    jobject jItem = env->CallObjectMethod(jIterator, nextMid);
    /* do something with jItem */
}
```