# How can I convert ArrayList<Integer> in Java to C++ int array using JNI?

Tags: java, c++, arraylist, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI to call c++ methods in my java client. In one of the methods, I'm passing in an ArrayList of integers and want to get out an array of integers in c++. When I pass the ArrayList through the JNI, I get a jObject. How do I convert that object to an integer array?

I have found this post that is similar, but uses an arraylist of strings:
[JNI - java ArrayList conversion to c++ std::string*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403340/jni-java-arraylist-conversion-to-c-stdstring)

Any ideas on how to modify that do use integers? I tried just changing the std::string refrences to int, but with no luck.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776800/convert-vector-to-jobject-in-c-jni) might be helpful.

Comment: The seems to be doing the opposite, pass back an arraylist to java. It's not the JNI that I'm having trouble with, its the conversion from a jObject to an integer array that I'm having trouble with (where the jObject was an arraylist of integers in java)

Comment: simply walk the arrayList object via its size() and get(int) methods via jni

Comment: ... or convert the ArrayList<Integer> back into int[] before passing it back.

Answer (score 5):

First realize that ArrayList<> is a generic, and JNI doesn't know anything at all about generics.  Basically, to JNI, ArrayList<T> is ArrayList<Object>.  Second, you are surely talking about ArrayList<Integer>, not ArrayList<int> because the second is not possible (see [Why I can't have int in the type of ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349011/why-i-cant-have-int-in-the-type-of-arraylist)).  Let's look at converting this to an int[] in C++.  I'm not going to try to write code that compiles here, because JNI is a huge tedious PITA, but this is the right idea, without all of the bloated error-checking you will also need ;-)

FYI, anyone who calls more than 10 JNI methods starts looking for JNI-wrapper-generators for C++.  We've written our own in house, but I hear there are respectable open and commercial tools.

```
jobject arrayObj = ...
jclass arrayClass = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");
jmethodID sizeMid = env->GetMethodID(arrayClass, "size", "()I");
jclass integerClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
jmethodID intValueMid = env->GetMethodID(integerClass, "intValue", "()I");
jvalue arg;
jint size = env->CallIntMethodA(arrayObj, sizeMid, &arg);
int* cppArray = new int[size];
jmethodID getMid = env->GetMethodID(arrayClass, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arg.i = i;
    jobject element = env->CallIntMethodA(arrayObj, getMid, &arg);
    appArray[i] = env->CallIntMethodA(element, intValueMid, &arg);
    // you can't have an unlimited number of active local references.
    vm->DeleteLocalRef(element);
}
```